# How do I implement a JFrame button to begin a timer?

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe, jbutton

I have a simple program that just tells you how long since the program has started running. Here is the code (that works just as intended!)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Program extends JFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button;

    public Program() {
         
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        button = new JButton("Click Me!");
        button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        
        setTitle("Hello");
        setSize(1200,800);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void frame(Graphics g) throws InterruptedException{
        int decaseconds = 0;        
        int seconds = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int hours = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            i--;
            decaseconds += 1;
            if(decaseconds == 100) {
                decaseconds -= 100;
                seconds++;
            }
            if(seconds == 60) {
                seconds -= 60;
                minutes++;
            }
            if(minutes == 60) {
                minutes -= 60;
                hours++;
            }
            
            System.out.println(hours + " hours : " + minutes + " minutes : " + seconds + " seconds : " + decaseconds + " decaseconds ");
            
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 800);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawString(hours + " hours : " + minutes + " minutes : " + seconds + " seconds : " + decaseconds + " decaseconds", 100, 100);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("You have clicked the button");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Program p  = new Program();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            p.frame(p.getGraphics());
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to put a button in the program, where you click the button to start the timer. So I read a tutorial and found this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class ActionEventDemo implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JButton button=new JButton("Click Me");

    ActionEventDemo(){
        prepareGUI();
        buttonProperties();
    }

    public void prepareGUI(){
        frame.setTitle("My Window");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(200,200,400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void buttonProperties(){
        button.setBounds(130,200,100,40);
        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Changing Background Color
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.pink);

    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ActionEventDemo();
    }
}
```

I've tried to merge the two but I can't figure out why. Can someone tell me what I should do? Reminder: I want the program to start counting (like the first example) once I press the button.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply trying to copy, paste and merge other peoples code is one thing. But understanding what the code does and why is more important. You should understand the basics. For example, check out [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33488613/11441011) is a runnable example for a Swing Stopwatch. Which is basically what you want.

Comment: Oh no I do understand them, but I can't figure out the error messages I've been getting.

Comment: Then you should have posted a specific question about the error message(s) you are getting. Currently, your "question" is: "_I've tried to merge the two but I can't figure out why. Can someone tell me what I should do?_"

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `java.util.Timer timer` and initialize it with it's default constructor. Then change the actionPerformed code to

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Something, that should be executed every interval
        }
    }, 0, intervalInMilliseconds);
}
```

You might want to add a possibility to cancel the timer (`timer.cancel()`) though.